# Unknown GET 'admin/warmup' request to our azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

We recently tried out the premium plan for our azure functions and we are noticing a lot of requests for 'admin/warmup'. My guess is that it is part of the premium plan for keeping the function workers alive, but I couldn't find any documentation on this. Anybody knows if this is the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's correct!

Here's a snippet from Azure Functions HostController

[image]

```
 [HttpGet]
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("admin/warmup")]
 [Authorize(Policy = PolicyNames.AdminAuthLevelOrInternal)]
 [RequiresRunningHost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Warmup([FromServices] IScriptJobHost scriptHost)
 {
     await scriptHost.TryInvokeWarmupAsync();
     return Ok();
 }
```

The changes are made recently and the docs aren't updated with that yet. You can validate the same with this git commit:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/commit/30405116a72e90ab17e77d2c39787d2e7f6f9570

Comment: Thank you! Didn't occur to me to check the repo, but yeah, that makes sense :)

Comment: Does this mean that we could call this route periodically in a consumption plan and always have a ready instance - same as in a premium plan?

Comment: @Spiff: certainly!